# How to send/recieve audio with or without using AT commands in Sierra Wireless modem ?

Tags: at-command, modem

Device - Sierra Wireless MC7304

I have installed GobiSerial and GobitNet drivers but during voice calls, the modem's speaker isn't showing any activity of incoming audio.

OS - Ubuntu-14.04- (Kernel -  3.19.0-59-generic)
Modem Source : alsa_input.usb-Sierra_Wireless__Incorporated_MC7304_0123456789ABCDEF-10-MC7304.analog-mono
Modem Sink: alsa_output.usb-Sierra_Wireless__Incorporated_MC7304_0123456789ABCDEF-10-MC7304.analog-mono

Methods tried - AT commands & slqssdk API

Any ideas how to send/receive audio data of voice calls ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answered at - https://forum.sierrawireless.com/viewtopic.php?f=56&t=10086

Solution - 
Try the following settings:

```
AT!AVCFG=0,3,3
AT!AVSETPROFILE=0
AT!AVVOICE=1
```

Answer (score 1):

In a project, I have developed a Linux program that controls MC7304 recording/playback during the voice call. I have a MC7304 FW that support USB sound interface, which means MC7304 audio interface is detected as an USB sound card. Use aplay/arecord or any other tools for playback or recording.

Otherwise, like in my case, I use portaudio to control the sound card in my c++ program.

However, I suspect USB sound interface is deprecated, because it disappears from their leaflet.